# Using the same table alias twice in a query

Tags: sql, oracle, ansi-sql

My coworker, who is new to ANSI join syntax, recently wrote a query like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM table1 t1
       JOIN table2 t2 ON
            (t1.col_a = t2.col_a)
       JOIN table3 t3 ON
            (t2.col_b = t3.col_b)
       JOIN table3 t3 ON
             (t3.col_c = t1.col_c);
```

Note that table3 is joined to both table1 and table2 on different columns, but the two JOIN clauses use the same table alias for table3.

The query runs, but I'm unsure of it's validity.  **Is this a valid way of writing this query?**

I thought the join should be like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM table1 t1
       JOIN table2 t2 ON
            (t1.col_a = t2.col_a)
       JOIN table3 t3 ON
            (t2.col_b = t3.col_b AND
             t3.col_c = t1.col_c);
```

**Are the two versions functionally identical?**  I don't really have enough data in our database yet to be sure.

Thanks.

Comment: It probably runs because both alias point to the same table, so there's no ambiguity, which is what the query analyzer / optimizer always complains about.

Comment: By the way the brackets aren't needed (they aren't part of the syntax so they are ignored). In my experience they confuse the heck out of code formatters.

Comment: I must admit I was surprised that this works. I agree with you that the construction seems perverse and hard to validate, even if it is in fact valid.

Comment: I agree that the parens are unnecessary, and I wouldn't have used them, but my coworker did.  We're all Oracle programmers, so none of us are expert at the ANSI syntax, but I've been using it for a few years now, and everybody else is just starting because it just recently became an official standard for us.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first query is a join of 4 tables, the second one is a join of 3 tables. So I don't expect that both queries return the same numbers of rows.

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
       JOIN table2 t2 ON
            (t1.col_a = t2.col_a)
       JOIN table3 t3 ON
            (t2.col_b = t3.col_b)
       JOIN table3 t3 ON
             (t3.col_c = t1.col_c);
```

The alias `t3` is only used in the ON clause. The alias `t3` refers to the table before the ON keyword. I found this out by experimenting. So the pervious query is equvivalent to

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
       JOIN table2 t2 ON
            (t1.col_a = t2.col_a)
       JOIN table3 t3 ON
            (t2.col_b = t3.col_b)
       JOIN table3 t4 ON
             (t4.col_c = t1.col_c);
```

and this can be transfotmed in a traditional join

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1,
       table2 t2,
       table3 t3,
       table3 t4
where (t1.col_a = t2.col_a)
    and  (t2.col_b = t3.col_b)
    and (t4.col_c = t1.col_c);
```

The second query is

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
       JOIN table2 t2 ON
            (t1.col_a = t2.col_a)
       JOIN table3 t3 ON
            (t2.col_b = t3.col_b AND
             t3.col_c = t1.col_c);
```

This can also transformed in a traditional join

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1,
    table2 t2,
    table3 t3
where (t1.col_a = t2.col_a)
    and (t2.col_b = t3.col_b)
    AND (t3.col_c = t1.col_c);
```

These queries seem to be different. To proof their difference we use the following example:

```
create table table1(
    col_a number,
    col_c number
);

create table table2(
    col_a number,
    col_b number
);

create table table3(
    col_b number,
    col_c number
);

insert into table1(col_a, col_c) values(1,3);
insert into table1(col_a, col_c) values(4,3);
insert into table2(col_a, col_b) values(1,2);
insert into table2(col_a, col_b) values(4,2);
insert into table3(col_b, col_c) values(2,3);
insert into table3(col_b, col_c) values(2,5);
insert into table3(col_b, col_c) values(7,9);

commit;
```

We get the following output

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
       JOIN table2 t2 ON
            (t1.col_a = t2.col_a)
       JOIN table3 t3 ON
            (t2.col_b = t3.col_b)
       JOIN table3 t3 ON
             (t3.col_c = t1.col_c)


| COL_A | COL_C | COL_A | COL_B | COL_B | COL_C | COL_B | COL_C |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|     1 |     3 |     1 |     2 |     2 |     3 |     2 |     3 |
|     4 |     3 |     4 |     2 |     2 |     3 |     2 |     3 |
|     1 |     3 |     1 |     2 |     2 |     5 |     2 |     3 |
|     4 |     3 |     4 |     2 |     2 |     5 |     2 |     3 |



             
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
       JOIN table2 t2 ON
            (t1.col_a = t2.col_a)
       JOIN table3 t3 ON
            (t2.col_b = t3.col_b AND
             t3.col_c = t1.col_c)

| COL_A | COL_C | COL_A | COL_B | COL_B | COL_C |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|     4 |     3 |     4 |     2 |     2 |     3 |
|     1 |     3 |     1 |     2 |     2 |     3 |
```

The number of rows retrieved is different and so `count(*)` is different.

The usage of the aliases was surprising. at least for me.

The following query works because `t1` in the `where_clause` references `table2`.

```
select *
from table1 t1 join table2 t1 on(1=1)
where t1.col_b<0;
```

The following query works because `t1` in the `where_clause` references `table1`.

```
select *
from table1 t1 join table2 t1 on(1=1)
where t1.col_c<0;
```

The following query raises an error because both `table1` and `table2` contain a column `col_a`.

```
select *
from table1 t1 join table2 t1 on(1=1)
where t1.col_a<0;
```

The error thrown is

```
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

The following query works, the alias `t1` refers to two different tables in the same `where_clause`.

```
select *
from table1 t1 join table2 t1 on(1=1)
where t1.col_b<0 and t1.col_c<0;
```

These and more examples can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84feb/12

### The smallest counter example

The smallest counter example is

```
table1
col_a  col_c
    1      2

table2
col_a  col_b
    1      3

table3
col_b  col_c
    3      5
    6      2
```

Here the second query has an empty result set and the first query returns one row. It can be shown that the `count(*)` of the second query never exeeds the `count(*)`of the first query.

#### A more detailed explanation

This behaviour will became more clear if we analyze the following statement in detail.

```
SELECT t.col_b, t.col_c
  FROM table1 t
       JOIN table2 t ON
            (t.col_b = t.col_c) ;
```

Here is  the reduced syntax for this query in Backus–Naur form derived from the syntax descriptions in the [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html) of Oracle 12.2. Note that under each syntax diagram there is a link to the *Backus–Naur* form of this diagram, e.g [Description of the illustration select.eps](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/img_text/select.html). "reduced" means that I left out all the possibilities that where not used, e,g. the `select` is defined as

```
select::=subquery [ for_update_clause ] ;
```

Our query does not use the optional `for_update_clause`, so I reduced the rule to

```
select::=subquery
```

The only exemption is the optional `where-clause`. I didn't remove it so that this reduced rules can be used to analyze the above query even if we add a `where_clause`.

These reduced rule will define only a subset of all possible select statements.

```
select::=subquery 
subquery::=query_block
query_block::=SELECT select_list FROM join_clause [ where_clause ]
join_clause::=table_reference  inner_cross_join_clause ...  
table_reference::=query_table_expression  t_alias query_table_expression::=table
inner_cross_join_clause::=JOIN table_reference ON condition
```

So our select statement is a `query_block` and the `join_clause` is of type

```
table_reference inner_cross_join_clause
```

where `table_reference` is `table1 t` and `inner_cross_join_clause` is `JOIN table2 t ON (t.col_b = t.col_c)`. The ellipsis `...` means that there could be additional inner_cross_join_clauses, but we do not need this here.

in the `inner_cross_join_clause` the alias `t` refers to `table2`. Only if these references cannot be satisfied the aliasmust be searched in an outer scope. So all the following expressions in the ONcondition are valid:

```
t.col_b = t.col_c
```

Here `t.col_b` is `table2.col_b` because `t` refers to the alias of its `inner_cross_join_clause`, `t.col_c` is `table1.col_c`. `t` of the `inner_cross_join_clause` (refering to `table2`) has no column `col_c` so the outer scope will be searched and an appropriate alias will be found.

If we have the clause

```
t.col_a = t.col_a
```

the alias can be found as alias defined in the `inner_cross_join_clause` to which this ON-`condition` belongs so `t` will be resolved to `table2`.

if the select list consists of

```
t.col_c, t.col_b, t.col_a
```

instead of `*` then the `join_clause` will be searched for an alias and `t.col_c` will be resolved to `table1.col_c` (`table2` does not contain a column `col_c`),  `t.col_b` will be resolved to `table2.col_b` (`table1` does not contain a `col_b`) but `t.col_a` will raise the error

```
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

because for the select_list none of the aias definition has a precedenve over the other. If our query also has a `where_clause` then the aliases are resolved in the same way as if they are used in the `select_list`.

Comment: That might be the most comprehensive answer I've ever seen to any question ever posted on Stackoverflow!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

With more data, it will produce different results.
Your colleagues query is same as this.

```
select * from table3 where t3.col_b = 'XX'
union
select * from table3 where t3.col_c = 'YY'
```

or

```
select * from table3 where t3.col_b = 'XX' or t3.col_c = 'YY'
```

while your query is like this.

```
select * from table3 where t3.col_b ='XX' and t3.col_c='YY'
```

First one is like data where (xx or yy) while second one is data where ( xx and yy)

Comment: Thanks.  I've been looking at the tables more closely, and it looks like the clause joining table3 to table1 is not necessary in either version, due to the way table2 joins to both of the others.  The specifics of that don't really come through in the generic version I posted above.

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation for this answer? I've never seen this syntax before, but I don't think it is exactly equivalent to a `union all` (since I get additional columns joining with the same alias) and I don't understand the more general case (since I can left outer join the same table with the same alias which confuses me). I'd like to read more about this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. You can check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4a8cc/6 for different queries. union all can produce duplicate rows depending on data conditions. So, if you use just union to eliminate duplicate, results will be same and logical operations are basically the same. and looks like assigning same alias only works in Oracle.

Comment: Above comment was about union all and union how it produce different number of rows because of duplicate rows elimination and regarding the different columns you see when using join vs union or union all, I used union to show the different data sets each query selects from the table3, the selection criteria.

Comment: Definitely not equivalent to a `union all` - it's equivalent to a Cartesian join.

Comment: Because `union all` is confusing people, I added simple select query. They produce same dataset from the table3, which has same effect as colleague's joining same table twice with different column. You can see that on sqlfiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4a8cc/6). @mathguy, I don't think you are right about Cartesian Join. The colleague's query still is a inner join. To be a Cartesian, on clause shouldn't have any condition.

Comment: It is a Cartesian join to the second instance of `table3` **only**. First the inner join of `table1`, `table2` and first instance of `table3` is performed; the result of this three-table inner join is then **cross-joined** (Cartesian join) to the second instance of `table3`, because there are no conditions on this second instance. All conditions apply only to the first instance of `table3` - even those that *seem* to be in the last join. The last set of join conditions simply further filter the result of the join of the "first three" tables (excluding the second instance of `table3`).

Comment: I think I kinda simplified it in sqlfiddle link provided. The result was not total rows times total rows.